# Conditionally setting parameter in yml file (Azure pipeline): VAR not updating

Tags: docker, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

## Problem

I want to set a parameter conditionally based on which branch triggered the pipeline. If the triggered branch was **feature/automated-testing**, I would like to set a parameter equal to "True". See the code below.

Parts of my `pipeline.yml` file looks like so:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feature/automated-testing

...

# Global variables for the pipeline
variables:
  - name: "triggerRepoName"
    value: "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"


stages:
  # common stage. Docker build, tag and push
  - stage: BuildDockerImage
    displayName: "Build docker image"
    variables:
     ...

    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/my-prject.yml@templates
        parameters:
          ${{ if eq( variables.triggerRepoName, 'feature/automated-testing') }}:
            runTests: "True"
          ${{ if ne(variables.triggerRepoName, 'feature/automated-testing') }}:
            runTests: "False"
```

## Question

When I push from branch `feature/automated-testing` and ´echo´ the variable runTests in the Dockerfile, it is blank. Is there something wrong with my syntax in the conditional statement?

I believe the error is in the way the variable is set conditionally, and I have therefore chosen not to supply the Dockerfile nor the other .yml template .yml used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change `variables.triggerRepoName` to `variables['triggerRepoName']`. It should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to learn YAML and I'm curious why this solution works while OP's initial approach doesn't? If you can share some insight to your answer please do. Thanks.